# IOS web view handling phone numbers

Tags: ios, uiwebview

I am using `UIWebView` to show some data.
`UIWebView` is detecting phone numbers, which is fine, but when the user clicks on the phone number it is trying to fire a call directly.

Is there any way I can show an confirm message after a user clicks on a phone number, to allow the user to confirm they would like to place a call to this number?

Answer (score 0):

Did you try to putting a breakpoint in shouldStartLoadWithRequest delegate method of UIWebview ? You might be able to catch the event click there.

Answer (score 0):

There is no part of UIWebView that allows you to know when a phone number has been clicked. You will either have to turn of phone number detection or detect phone numbers yourself and convert them to links manually, so will have control over what happens when you click them.